# The importance of WebGL in the future of game development

Tags: webgl

I've recently stumbled upon some pretty impressive *Babylon.js* and *PlayCanvas* demos.

- [Babylon.js example](http://www.babylonjs.com/Demos/PBR/)
- [PlayCanvas example](https://tanx.playcanvas.com/?u=um4zmbo4vtkradge)

As a reminder: these frameworks allow 3D rendering in any (up to date) web browser, using the *WebGL* library.

Along with *node.js* and *Socket.io*, those 3D engines make it possible to release real-time multiplayer 3D games.

For sure, such games will never compare to AAA titles running in more native environnments.
But a part of today's video game industry is leaning towards more simple, accessible games. Think about strategy games or (MMO)RPGs for example (or anything that doesn't require very low latency and high reactivity, like FPS do). Those Javascript libraries could do a pretty good job at it.

In addition, they make it easy to create multiplatform games, since any modern device with a web browser can run your game.

Another advantage is the "one click" accessibility (*i.e.* someone sends you an url -> you click on it -> you're playing the game), which can be a crucial advantage to spread your game.

I've seen some Unity games which could have been made in WebGL with only little drop in performances and visual quality (though I may be wrong here). And they could have benefited a lot from being playable in web browsers.

I'm actually surprised that we haven't already heard of some massively played 3D Web game. Why is it so? Do you think it will change in the future?

Even if one wants to argue that web-games aren't mature enough for 3D, then what about 2D? So many people are using engines such as Unity or Unreal 4 for relatively "simple" 2D games, while they could have made something totally similar with today's javascript, and potentially reached a wider audience.

Comment: That is heavily opinion based and therefore not fit for this website. How the importance of WebGL will develop can only be speculated, one must await the future...